# Obter um item de cada Row

Tags: java, mysql

Como posso obter um Item de cada Row?

Por exemplo, tenho uma coluna com as seguintes Rows:

- TESTE
- TESTE
- TESTE2
- TESTE2
- TESTE3

Como eu queria:

- TESTE
- TESTE2
- TESTE3

Meu código:

```
public void carregar(){
        qy = "SELECT TESTEROWS FROM COLUNA";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = MySQL.getConn().prepareStatement(qy);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                setItem(TypeItem.valueOf(rs.getString("Type")));
            }
            loadItemsLoja();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Com while ele só está retornando todos (óbvio), com if ele só me retorna o primeiro. Como posso obter um de cada Row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só utilizar [SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

`SELECT distinct(TESTEROWS) FROM COLUNA`

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de fazer isso:

```
SELECT distinct TESTEROWS FROM COLUNA
```

ou

```
SELECT TESTEROWS FROM COLUNA group by TESTEROWS
```